# Pine Strategy barstate.islast false

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, tradingview-api

### Scenario

Considering a 5 Minute Time Frame, adding two indicator to the chart - `Test Indicator` and `Test Strategy` -  before the close of the Candle.

### `barstate.islast` is False

`barstate.islast` is false for the last bar in `Strategy`, while it is true for `Indicator`.

Indicator Example

```pine
//@version=5
indicator("Test Indicator", overlay=true)

plotchar(barstate.islast, "islast", "", location = location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

Strategy Example

```pine
//@version=5
strategy("Test Strategy", overlay=true)

plotchar(barstate.islast, "islast", "", location = location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

[image: Results comparison for Indicator and Strategy]

### Additional Information

After the close of the 5 Minute Candle, the value `barstate.islast` is the same for `Indicator` and `Strategy`, even for the Last and Current Candle.

We can get the same behavior adding `calc_on_every_tick = true` for the strategy.

[image: The result are the same after the close of the first bar]

### Questions

Why the different behavior for `bartstate.islast`, between `Strategy` and `Indicator`, where `bartstate.islast` is `false` for `Strategy`,  before the close of the last candle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, strategies are calculated when the bar is closed. That's why it returns `false` when it is an active bar because your strategy is not being executed on every tick.